# viewDidDisappear never get called in customized tab

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am using dropdown menu, want to achieve the same behaviour like tab bar. For example, I want to switch vc1,vc2,vc3 in any time and keep original data.       What I do is using willMoveToParentViewController.

```
   func didSelectItem(indexPath: Int){
    // Initialize View controllers
    switch(indexPath){
    case 1:
        self.removeFromParentViewController()
        vc1.title = "Learning Stories"
        self.addChildViewController(vc1)
        self.view.addSubview(vc1.view)
          vc1.willMoveToParentViewController(self)

    case 2:
        self.removeFromParentViewController()
        vc2.title = "Group Stories"
        self.addChildViewController(vc2)
        self.view.addSubview(vc2.view)
        vc2.willMoveToParentViewController(self)


    default:
        self.removeFromParentViewController()
        self.addChildViewController(vc3)
        self.view.addSubview(vc3.view)
        vc3.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
}
```

but in vc2 and vc3, viewDidappear only called once, and viewDIdappear never get called. I know it should only work on pop,present etc, but how tab bar does? to keep the data when you switching each viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

you are bypassing the view life cycle stuff by adding the view/vc like that it seems because they arent actually going away, you never remove the other 2 viewcontrollers when you are swapping to another one it looks like. So technically they are all being added to the same view, but each time you call `addSubview` you are just taking the view and putting it on top of the other ones. Even though they arent visible, they havent actually gone anywhere and thats why its not calling `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: how to make it like tab bar, swapping each vc and keep the data as well. It seems like if I doing in my way, it would cost more memory?

Comment: in each of your cases, you need some code to make sure the other 2 vc's are removed, just experiment a bit

Comment: All I found are about tabbar controller and Navigation controller. What I need Is something same with tabbar does. A -> B, or A->C,  C->A etc, and retain data.  If I remove other 2vc, how can I retain the data?

Comment: have some sort of object that stores your data that is disjoint from your viewcontrollers, so that when the viewcontroller reappears, you can populate the data back. this is standard MVC stuff